# CCScene addChild Transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've got a CCScene and I'm adding a CCLayer to it via addChild:

```
[self addChild:helloWorldLayer];
```

Is there a way to add this child with a transition similar to how you can do this?

```
[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.00f scene:[HelloWorldScene scene]];
```

Comment: I've found that dealing with CCFade can be risky. Not all nodes implement a version of fade (as @LearnCocos2D mentioned). If you are getting errors, particularly along the lines of 'no such scheduler exists', expect to find CCFade as the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorldScene scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Most transitions use a [regular CCAction](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_action_interval.html) to perform its job. To fade the layer in, use the CCFade action.

The downside: not all transitions are backed by actions, and actions may work differently on layers than in a transition. If in doubt, look at the code of the transition class to learn which action it uses and how it is used.